# Swift best way to store local files / ressources for Release for Mac

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am working on a SwiftUI app for MacOS. The app stores many files (Pdf, Images) locally. I always used following code to store my files...

```
do {
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    fileUrl5 = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("Test.pdf")

    try dataDoc5.write(to: fileUrl5, options: .atomic)
}
```

This worked perfectly in Sandbox mode, when testing on local Mac. Now I deployed my App, and didn't run it in simulator. Now all files getting stored in the Documents folder of the User. It is correct because I used `.documentDirectory`. This brought my question:

1. Where do I correctly store my local files? What folder is supposed to be the Documents folder for my app? Where should I store all these files (especially keeping in mind to make it accessable with iCloud later on)

Comment: In your app's Application Support folder?

Comment: Simulator?  What do you mean by that?  You are supposed to use the sandbox folder assigned to your application.

Comment: Thank you @matt. That was what I was searching for the whole time. Then I can use FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
Will that point directly to my director? When I run it in Xcode it looks like it points to Application Support folder in general not my app specific

Comment: @ElTomato Yeah I mean that sandbox folder. When using sandbox I get a different folder for development correct?

Comment: When using sandbox you get a different folder forever. That’s what a sandbox is. You get your own area, unable to harm other apps or the user.

Comment: @matt Thanks, now I understand sandbox much better. So your approach would be to add a folder to Applications Support and store it there?

Comment: @davidev you should take a look at File System Basics https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the link. Will read! :)